# What's wrong with my PHP date

Tags: php

It's 6:32 PM EST yet H is being returned as 22.
I would expect it to be 18.
PHP is version 5.3.9

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php 
$time = date("H");

if( $time >= 06 && $time < 10 )
$img_name = 'sunrise.jpg';
if( $time >= 10 && $time < 17 )
$img_name = 'day.jpg';
if( $time >= 17 && $time < 19 )
$img_name = 'sunset.jpg';
if( $time >= 19 && $time < 06 )
$img_name = 'night.jpg';


?>
```

Comment: You should set the timezone: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Are you sure the timezone is configured correctly on the server? See what `date_default_timezone_get()` says.

Comment: Hint: How can a number be >= 19 *and* simultaneously < 6?

Comment: tadman, what is the proper condition to test/evaluate? for a number greater than or equal to 19 AND smaller than 6. What's the proper condition to test if the time is between 7pm and 6am?

Comment: Use `date('G')`, 24 hour time without leading 0. Then remove leading 0 in all comparison values. `$time < 6 || $time >= 19`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible things:

1. Your server time could be off. Check the server it is hosted on to make sure it's not
2. **Set a timezone**. We can tell PHP which timezone to use by doing this:

   date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

You can view a list of supported timezones here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php